# Do measurable maps preserve stationary ergodicity?

Tags: time-series, stochastic-processes, stationarity, ergodic

In a recent effort to establish stationary ergodicity for a certain stochastic process, I just happened to come across a statement, which I find to be little bit confounding.

Given two measurable spaces $(\,E,\mathcal{E}\,)$ and $(\,\tilde{E},\tilde{\mathcal{E}}\,)$, let $(v_t)_{\,t\in\mathbb{Z}}$ be a stationary ergodic sequence of $E$-valued random elements and define a measurable function $f:{E}^\mathbb{N}\to \tilde{E}$. Then the sequence $(\tilde{v}_t)_{\,t\in\mathbb{Z}}$ defined by 
$$\tilde{v}_t=f(v_t,v_{t-1},...)\qquad \text{for all  }\quad t\in\mathbb{Z}$$
is stationary ergodic. (Straumann and Mikosch, 2006, p. 2455 - https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1169571804)

I do have to admit that I am somewhat irritated by this statement. In particular, let $f$ be prescribed by
$$(v_t,v_{t-1},...)\,\mapsto\,\sum_{j=0}^\infty\rho^jv_{t-j}.$$
Then, I'd argue that $(\tilde{v}_t)_{\,t\in\mathbb{Z}}$ is not necessarily stationary (as would follow from the statement above). In fact, stationarity of $\tilde{v}_t$ would depend on whether $|\rho|<1$ or not.

I'd very much appreciate, if someone could tell me where I am going wrong, what I am missing, or whether the statement is not entirely accurate.

For reference, the statement is supposed to build on proposition 4.3 (p. 26) in Ulrich Krengel's (1985) monograph [*Ergodic Theorems*](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=t4_BDh8gt2kC).

Comment: $f$ must be a measurable map. If $\rho > 1$, it's not even clear you have a map, $\omega$ by $\omega$.